# angular routerlink doesn't work until I refresh the page

Tags: angular, router

I'm trying to navigate to another page using angular's routerlink, but it's not working until I refresh the page. I tried doing the navigation from the TS file instead , but I'm facing the same issue. Any thoughts on what might be the problem ? thanks!

**navigation using routerLink:**

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/','view', 'members'>{{ members }}</a>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**and from the TS file, I tried this :**

```
  goToViewMembers(): void {
        let link = `/view/members`;
        this.router.navigateByUrl(link);
    }
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Instead of `<a [routerLink]="['/','view', 'members']">` (added the missing ] and "), you can simply use `<a routerLink="/view/members">`. Also, did you set up the route correctly?

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way, plus I just tried to simplify the link , there are other parts of it that include ids that I get from the ts.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but none of the replies to this or similar questions helped me with this problem.
I was also having an issue where clicking a link on my navbar did not properly add the 'active' class until I had actually refreshed my page manually. It turned out the route was not being properly recorded until the refresh took place. Here is my solution:

```
//styles.css
.active {
    background-color: white;
}

// navbar.component.html
<nav class="navbar navbar-horizontal">
    <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['linkA/']" class="nav-item nav-link">LinkA</a>
    <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['linkB/']" class="nav-item nav-link">LinkB</a>
</nav>

// navbar.component.ts
constructor(router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    router.navigated = true;
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a routerLink="view/members">{{ members }}</a>
```

Or if you want to use variables, you can do it like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="'view/members/' +  variable">{{ members }}</a>
```

Comment: it's the same thing , and it doesn't work until I refresh the current page .

Comment: If so then the issue is not how you use routerLink, share the rest of the code